# Python 2.7 | copy file with folder structure

Tags: python-2.7, copy

having below directory structure.

```
home/
└── jobs/
    ├── jobname1/
    │   ├── builds/
    │   └── config.xml
    └── jobname2/
        ├── builds/
        └── config.xml
```

having many job names under jobs folder.
I wish to copy all config.xml files to another backup directory without missing its jobname folder structure.

could you please help me understand how to use shutil libraray in more efficient way.

My target folder Backup structure something like below

```
Backup/
└── jobs/
    ├── jobname1/
    │   └── config.xml
    └── jobname2/
        └── config.xml
```

Please help.
Please find below my actual requirement.

Algorithm to write python2.7 scrpt

```
    1. git clone Backup folder , where Backup is empty folder
    2. Find list of files having file name "config.xml in the HOME folder
    3. Copy all config.xml files to Backup folder with out changing the folder structure
            3.1. If config.xml is new file then git add  all config.xml to git repository , and commit followed by git push
            3.2. If config.xml is existing and unchanged then git push is not required
            3.3. If config.xml is existing and modified then commit followed by git push
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the logic. May be this might be useful to someone. Regret the code as it is novice level.

```
                def walkfs(self,findfile):
                    ## dictionary to store full path of each source findfile
                    matches_fullpath_dict = {}
                    ## dictionary to store relative path of each findfile
                    matches_trunc_dict = {}
                    ## dictionary to store full path of each target file location
                    matches_target_fullpath_dict = {}
                    i =0
                    source = self.jenkins_Home
                    destination = self.backupRepositoryPath
                    for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(source):            
                        for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, findfile):
                            i=i+1
                            matches_fullpath_dict[i]=os.path.join(root, filename)
                            matches_trunc_dict[i]=os.path.join(root.replace(source,""), filename)                
                            matches_target_fullpath_dict[i]=os.path.join( os.path.sep, destination + root.replace(source,""))


                    keys = matches_target_fullpath_dict.keys()
                    for key in keys:
                        if not os.path.exists(matches_target_fullpath_dict.get(key)):
                            try:
                                os.makedirs(matches_target_fullpath_dict.get(key))
                            except OSError:
                                pass

                    keys = matches_target_fullpath_dict.keys()
                    for key in keys:
                        shutil.copy2(matches_fullpath_dict.get(key,None), matches_target_fullpath_dict.get(key,None))
```